# agregar textbox dinamicos desde un boton

Tags: php, javascript, html, bootstrap

trato de generar textbox para hacer el calculo de un plazo pero no logro que los texbox salgan separados y en una sola fila

me sale de esta forma
[image: Asi me queda]

quisiera que quedara de esta manera
[image: quisiera que quedara como esta inmagen espero me puedan ayudar]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title></title>

    <!-- Bootstrap 4.0 -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  </head>

  <body>

    <!--Code by Byspel.com -->
    <!--Code by Byspel.com -->

    <!-- Contenedor -->
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">

        <div class="col-lg-10">
          <!-- Card -->
          <div class="card w-75">

            <div class="container">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                  <br>
                  <!-- Titulo del Card -->

                  <br>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                  <form id="" action="">

                    <!-- Productos -->
                    <div class="form-group"> 
                      <label for="state_id" class="control-label">Plazos</label>
                      <!-- Boton Agregar -->
                      <input class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" type="button" title="Agregar Producto" Value="+" onclick="agregar()">
                      <!-- Boton Borrar -->
                      <input class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" type="button" title="Borrar Producto" Value="-" onclick="borrar()">
                      <br>
                      <br>
                      <!-- Div donde se añadiran los Selects -->
                      <div id="plazos">
                      </div>

                      <br>  
                      <input class="btn btn-info btn-sm " type="submit"  Value="Guardar" >
                    </div>
                  </form>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <script language="JavaScript">
      //Creacion de Variable incremental
      var incremento = 0;

      //Lo que se hará cuando se presione el boton de Agregar
      function agregar(obj)
      {

        incremento++;


        //Obteniendo el Div "plazos"
        bloque = document.getElementById('plazos');



        //Creando el input que irá dentro del Div "plazos"
        elemento = document.createElement('input');
        elemento.setAttribute("class", "custom-input custom-input-sm-1 mb-3" );
        elemento.id = 'input'+incremento;
        bloque.appendChild(elemento);

        elemento = document.createElement('input');
        elemento.setAttribute("class", "custom-input custom-input-sm-1 mb-2" );
        elemento.id = 'input2'+incremento;
        bloque.appendChild(elemento);


      }


      //Lo que se hará cuando se presione el boton de Borrar
      function borrar(obj) {
        incremento = incremento - 1;
        bloque = document.getElementById('plazos');
        bloque.removeChild(bloque.lastChild);
      }
    </script>
    <footer>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </footer>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: podes agregar como te esta quedando ahora?

Answer (score 0):

Podes agregar un simple `margin-left` y crear un elemento `br` asi:

```css
.custom-input {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title></title>

    <!-- Bootstrap 4.0 -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  </head>

  <body>

    <!--Code by Byspel.com -->
    <!--Code by Byspel.com -->

    <!-- Contenedor -->
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">

        <div class="col-lg-10">
          <!-- Card -->
          <div class="card w-75">

            <div class="container">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                  <br>
                  <!-- Titulo del Card -->

                  <br>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                  <form id="" action="">

                    <!-- Productos -->
                    <div class="form-group"> 
                      <label for="state_id" class="control-label">Plazos</label>
                      <!-- Boton Agregar -->
                      <input class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" type="button" title="Agregar Producto" Value="+" onclick="agregar()">
                      <!-- Boton Borrar -->
                      <input class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" type="button" title="Borrar Producto" Value="-" onclick="borrar()">
                      <br>
                      <br>
                      <!-- Div donde se añadiran los Selects -->
                      <div id="plazos">
                      </div>

                      <br>  
                      <input class="btn btn-info btn-sm " type="submit"  Value="Guardar" >
                    </div>
                  </form>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <script language="JavaScript">
      //Creacion de Variable incremental
      var incremento = 0;

      //Lo que se hará cuando se presione el boton de Agregar
      function agregar(obj)
      {

        incremento++;


        //Obteniendo el Div "plazos"
        bloque = document.getElementById('plazos');



        //Creando el input que irá dentro del Div "plazos"
        elemento = document.createElement('input');
        elemento.setAttribute("class", "custom-input custom-input-sm-1 mb-3" );
        elemento.id = 'input'+incremento;
        bloque.appendChild(elemento);

        elemento = document.createElement('input');
        elemento.setAttribute("class", "custom-input custom-input-sm-1 mb-2" );
        elemento.id = 'input2'+incremento;
        bloque.appendChild(elemento);
        var br = document.createElement('br');
        bloque.appendChild(br);
      }


      //Lo que se hará cuando se presione el boton de Borrar
      function borrar(obj) {
        incremento = incremento - 1;
        bloque = document.getElementById('plazos');
        bloque.removeChild(bloque.lastChild);
      }
    </script>
    <footer>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </footer>

  </body>

</html>
```